# Package 'bind9' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, bind

I'm tying to install a DNS server on Ubuntu 14.04. I get the error (`Package 'bind9' has no installation candidate`), and the `apt-get update` command doesn't work.

Comment: Please elaborate; "the command is not working" is not useful. "I tried running `<command>` and instead of the expected output I got <xxxxxx>" is much better.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `bind9` is pretty terrible. You really want [`PowerDNS`](https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/installation.html) instead.

Second, Ubuntu 14 is /ancient/ by internet standards. Consider upgrading to a more recent and better supported version - I think 18 is the most recent one.

Third, the "No installation candidate" issue has an explanation and possible cause in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean). Check if the solutions offered in that answer help your case.

That said, even with pdns running and administering a DNS server is a nontrivial task. Perhaps you'd be better served with explaining what you're trying to accomplish and why you think running a private DNS server is the most viable solution (See also: [XY problems](http://xyproblem.info/))